# Change STDIN with a pipe and it's a directory

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I have this

```
pipe_in, pipe_out = IO.pipe

fork do
    # child 1
    pipe_in.close
    STDOUT.reopen pipe_out
    STDERR.reopen pipe_out
    puts "Hello World"
    pipe_out.close
end

fork do
    # child 2
    pipe_out.close

    STDIN.reopen pipe_in

    while line = gets
        puts 'child2:' + line
    end

    pipe_in.close
end

Process.wait
Process.wait
```

`get` will always raise an error saying "gets: Is a directory", which doesn't make sense to me. If I change `gets` to `pipe_in.gets` it works. What I want to know is, why doesn't `STDIN.reopen pipe_in` and `gets` not work?

Comment: The code works except a few things forgotten. It looks to be a problem with rake, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8212799/398640

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me, with the following change:

```
     pipe_in.close
 end

+pipe_in.close
+pipe_out.close
+
 Process.wait
 Process.wait
```

Without this change, you still have the pipes open in the original process, so the reader will never see an end of file.  That is, process doing the wait still had the write pipe open leading to a deadlock.

Comment: Interesting. For some reason it does not work in `rake` but it does work in `irb`. I'll start a new question on that.